# Python/matplotlib : getting rid of matplotlib.mpl warning

Tags: python, matplotlib, deprecation-warning

I am using matplotlib using python 3.4.
When I start my program, I have the following warning message:

> C:\Python34-32bits\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py:123:
>   MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The matplotlib.mpl module was deprecated
>   in version 1.3. Use `import matplotlib as mpl` instead.
>   warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)

As far as I know I do not use mpl, and all my imports concerning matplotlib are:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

Anything I should do ?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can suppress that particular warning, which is probably the preferred way:

```
import warnings
import matplotlib.cbook
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=matplotlib.cbook.mplDeprecation)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can [temporarily suppress a warning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings), when importing

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to suppress that warning with the code below:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=UserWarning)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see the code, however remember to **set the parameters of the plot first, only then initialize the plot**.

*Exemple, what you may have done:*

```
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
```

*What you have to do:*

```
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to

`MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: mplDeprecation was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later ...`

use this instead:

```py
import warnings
import matplotlib
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=matplotlib.MatplotlibDeprecationWarning)
```